# DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'MonoPosixHelper' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, dll, apple-silicon, peachpie

I am trying to work with WordPress using the PeachPie compiler on an Apple Silicon Mac.
After running the command `dotnet run` i get the following error in the browser:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'MonoPosixHelper' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libMonoPosixHelper, 0x0001): tried: 'libMonoPosixHelper' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibMonoPosixHelper' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libMonoPosixHelper' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libMonoPosixHelper' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libMonoPosixHelper' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
at Peachpie.AspNetCore.Web.PhpHandlerMiddleware.InvokeScriptAsync(HttpContext context, ScriptInfo script, String path_info)
at PeachPied.WordPress.AspNetCore.Internal.WpResponseCacheMiddleware.CaptureResponse(HttpContext context)
at PeachPied.WordPress.AspNetCore.Internal.WpResponseCacheMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at PeachPied.WordPress.AspNetCore.Internal.DiagnosticExtensions.Middleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```